# Windows 10 Boot Issue (needs USB and ssd not in boot priority)

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, usb-flash-drive

I have 2 issues with my Windows 10 installation, but I'd like to give a background of what happened:

- I have 2 drives, SSD on M.2 slot and a HDD both on SATA
- I have an old Win 8.1 installation on one of the partitions of the HDD
- I have a bootable USB drive with a Win 10 installer (Zotac tool with Win 10 iso)

Firstly, I erased all partitions on my SSD (drive 0), and tried to install WIndows 10 there. It created 2 partitions (MSR and Primary) and completed the install.

I encountered a brief issue on one of the restarts, as it seemed like an infinite loop of trying to boot something. Turned off my PC and turned it on again and it seemed like it was booting fine already.

However, now I have 2 issues:

1. The SSD is no longer in the list of boot priorities when I enter the BIOS, when I check SATA config I still see the drive
2. When I remove the installation USB, Windows 10 will not boot

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove my HDD and reinstall everything on the SSD (needed to remove all partitions). Prior to this, Windows 10 didn't create 2 missing partitions:

1. The EFI Partition (for boot)
2. Recovery Partition